# Databinding to a Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

When I try to bind the data to a `GridView`, it shows nothing.

Here is the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
<Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="gridview" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="GridviewItemTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="250" Width="250" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationName}"   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="12" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And this is my code behind code

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

public IEnumerable<LocationPicture> Pictures
{
    get { return _pictures; }
    set { _pictures = value; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    CreateDummyList();
}

public void CreateDummyList()
{
    List<LocationPicture> pictures = new List<LocationPicture>();
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { 
                     ImageUri = "Images/1.jpg", 
                     LocationName = "location" 
                 });
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { 
                     ImageUri = "Images/2.jpg", 
                     LocationName = "location" 
                 });
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { 
                     ImageUri = "Images/3.jpg", 
                     LocationName = "location" 
                 });
    _pictures = pictures;
}
```

I just created a dummy list for the `GridView` and call the method in `onNavigatedTo`.

But it shows nothing on the `GridView`.

Comment: you need to set datacontext for your grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do the following:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

public ObservableCollection<LocationPicture> Pictures
{
    get { return _pictures; }
    set { _pictures = value; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    CreateDummyList();
}

public void CreateDummyList()
{
    List<LocationPicture> pictures = new ObservableCollection<LocationPicture>();
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { ImageUri = "Images/1.jpg", LocationName = "location" });
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { ImageUri = "Images/2.jpg", LocationName = "location" });
    pictures.Add(new LocationPicture { ImageUri = "Images/3.jpg", LocationName = "location" });

    _pictures = pictures;       
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

But it's better to move your collection to ViewModel class and bind the DataContext to it. See more about in [MVVM guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)